# Two questions on canonical line bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, vector-bundles

The  canonical  line  bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ is  denoted by $\ell_{n}$. It is  well known that: $$(\ell_{1}\otimes \ell_{1})\oplus1 \simeq\ell_{1}\oplus\ell_{1}$$ Both sides are isomorphic  bundles  as two  topological vector  bundles over $\mathbb{C}P^{1}$.The  argument is  explained in "K-theory  and  vector  bundles"  by  Allen  Hatcher. In fact the  argument is  based on the  fact that the  following two  maps from $S^{1}$ to $GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ are  homotopic  maps
$$\begin{pmatrix}z & 0\\ 0&z \end{pmatrix}\;\;\text{and}\begin{pmatrix}z^{2} & 0\\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

**(A topological question):**

> How can we  compare $(\ell_{n}\otimes \ell_{n})\oplus1 $  with $\ell_{n}\oplus\ell_{n}$. We know  that their  restriction to $\mathbb{C}P^{1}\subset \mathbb{C}P^{n}$ are isomorphic. So what is  the  **difference element**  as  an  element of the relative  K-theory $K(\mathbb{C}P^{n},\mathbb{C}P^{1})$?

**(An  algebra  geometric  question):**

> Is the  isometry $$(\ell_{1}\otimes \ell_{1})\oplus1 \simeq\ell_{1}\oplus\ell_{1}$$ valid  as an isomorphism of vector  bundles in   the  context  of  algebraic geometry?

Comment: Compare Chern characters.

Comment: @Sasha  could  you please more explain: in $\mathbb{Z} [x]/x^{n+1}$ , we have ${(e^{x})}^{2}+1=2e^{x}$ so what is the  contradiction?

Comment: No, this is false -- compare the coefficients of $x^2$.

Comment: As algebraic vector bundles, $(\ell_{1}\otimes \ell_{1})\oplus1$ and $\ell_{1}\oplus\ell_{1}$ -- or, in algebraic geometry language, $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)^2$ -- are not isomorphic. Any algebraic vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$ can be written $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(d_1)\oplus \ldots \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(d_r)$ with $d_1\leq \ldots \leq d_r$, and this decomposition is *unique*.

Comment: $(e^x)^2+1 = e^{2x}+1 = 2 + 2x + 2x^2 + \frac43 x^3 + \dots$ while $2e^x = 2 + 2x + x^2 + \frac13 x^3 + \dots$

Comment: @Sasha Thank you  very much  for  your  comments. I was incorrect in computation of  Chern  character.  What about the  "difference  element" as  an  element of relative  k theory?

Comment: @abx thank you very  much  for  your  comments  in particular your comment on algebra  geometric  part of  my  question.

Comment: @abx  could  you please give  me  an  elementary reference for classification of  algebraic  vector  bundle and the  uniquness of  decomposition which you mentioned?Thanks

Comment: This is not an elementary result, you need some basic facts on cohomology, Serre duality, etc.
 [These notes](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~clement/grothendiecks-thm.pdf) which I found through Google seems as accessible as possible.